# Revenue System based on Versioning/Trac/Ticket Statistics

Tags: trac

Lately I had the idea that a badge system system like stackoverflow's could be applied to trac (or whatever system) to stimulate your developers handle tickets, bugs and so on.
The naive approach would be very vulnerable to abuse (obviously).

The question is:
Is there a system like that is applied in a work process (non-community).
It might even be connected to monetary benefits.

I am not sure myself if this is even the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you read [The Defect Black Market](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Defect-Black-Market.aspx) first. :-)

Answer (score 1):

While slightly different, you may want to check out [The Continuous Integration Game, plugin for Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/The+Continuous+Integration+Game+plugin).  Users get points for doing certain things like completing tasks, fixing tests, etc. and you may be able to customize the points.

Hudson also has a [trac plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Trac+Plugin), maybe you can put them together and make something awesome.